# Negative Lookahead Regex for partial dom parsing

Tags: regex, regex-lookarounds

I am trying to get images encompassed in anchors. I know the good practice to do this is to parse the DOM, but i am trying to save memory here.

```
<a href=''><img src=''></a>
```

The solution of the above example is pretty straight forward `<a[^>]*?href=['\"](.*?)['\"][^>]*?>[\s\S]*?<img`. But in the more complex example

```
<a href=''></a><a href=''><img src=''></a>
```

that regex fails, and gathers the entire string with the wrong anchor, i need to add a negative lookahead somehow and what i am trying so far is `(?!</a>)<a[^>]*?href=['\"](.*?)['\"][^>]*?>[\s\S]*?<img` but for some reason it makes no difference.

Comment: Can I suggest a SAX parser? does a full parse without holding the whole DOM in memory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put a negative lookahead check for the in-between `.*` and `[\s\S]*` . Because it matches also the closing  anchor tag.

```
<a[^>]*?href=['\"](?:(?!<\/a>).)*?['\"][^>]*?>(?:(?!<\/a>)[\s\S])*?<img
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/hB2uR3/1)